# Word that means "live life happily and enjoy every second and every moment."

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use a word that means "live life happily and enjoy every second and every moment."

Comment: "Impossible" I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [*carpe diem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem)? I'm not sure.